# Javascript attach an onclick event to all links

Tags: javascript, events

I want to attach a function on every link on the site to change a parameter.

How can I do this without jQuery?

How do I traverse every link (it might be a DOM item) and call a function on them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) is supported by all modern browsers and all the way back to IE 6

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @Márcio totally depends on the specific use-case, might not be the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 102):

It's weird that nobody offered an alternative solution that uses event bubbling

```
function callback(e) {
    var e = window.e || e;

    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A')
        return;

    // Do something
}

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
else
    document.attachEvent('onclick', callback);
```

The pros of this solution is that when you dynamically add another anchor, you don't need to specifically bind an event to it, so all links will always fire this, even if they were added after these lines were executed. This is in contrast to all the other solutions posted so far. This solution is also more optimal when you have a large number of links on your page.

Comment: Someone recently added yet another answer that will add loads of event listeners but won't do anything for anchors added to the dom after the code executes. Such a simple principle but so many people seem to be completely unaware of.

Comment: I also think that this solution is better, because it adds only one event, versus potentially adding tens of events. This solution is also better, because if you dynamically add more links, it will work for them too!

Comment: It's great when someone tends to think deeply!

Comment: Only works if you don't have elements nested in your A tag

Comment: IT'S NOT WEIRD, for example Youtube site have a lot of A tag with nested elements and this method won't work

Comment: @Spoeken If you have elements in your anchor tag, go up the DOM tree looking for a parent anchor tag.

Comment: @MikeT You can also probably just add `pointer-events: none;` to the containing elements. For a production app I would choose a more controllable solution than this tho. Could potentially cause a lot of frustration for future developers or even yourself later down the line.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to offer an improvement on @zatatatata's answer which also works with links with nested elements.

```
function findLink(el) {
    if (el.tagName == 'A' && el.href) {
        return el.href;
    } else if (el.parentElement) {
        return findLink(el.parentElement);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

function callback(e) {
    const link = findLink(e.target);
    if (link == null) { return; }
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something here
};

document.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
```

If the clicked element isn't a link, we search its parents to check for a link element.

Answer (score 4):

```
function linkClickHandler(a) {
  console.log(a.host);
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) links[i].onclick = function() {
    linkClickHandler(links[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

better way:

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__item");

item.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("click", function () {
    link.classList.add("nav__item--active");
  });
});
```

Comment: How you can sure that all the links will have .nav__item class to bind with every anchor link

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be useful for you:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    i,
    len,
    el;

for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    el = elements[i];

    // Do what you need on the element 'el'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getElementsByTagName('a')`