# assign onclick event to several DOM elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

Is it possible to set the same onclick event to all elements of the same class / tag / etcetera? The following code does not work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("A").onclick = function(){alert("!")};
```

Comment: Try with this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492344/javascript-attach-an-onclick-event-to-all-link

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can loop each element and assign your listener

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; ++i) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        alert(elements[i].nodeValue);
    }, false);
}
```