# e.target references the image not the <a>

Tags: javascript

I have code that looks like this:

```
<a href="someline">
<img src="img.jpg"/>
</a>
```

I have code all over my page, to get the links, and get their href like this:

```
e.target.href
```

The problem is, when clicking the link that contains the image, then e.target is the image itself not the anchor tag. I tried setting the href on the image as a bad solution, but e.target.href is undefined on the image.

How do I solve it so that e.target will reference the `<a>` not the image.

Comment: So basically you want to target the parent elements of the image? Maybe try using `target.parentElement`

Comment: How are you hooking up those event handlers?

Comment: It depends on where are you picking the event from. If you are picking it from the image then of course the e.target will return the image object instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8496919/4281779

Comment: Example https://jsfiddle.net/vrp06LL2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the `onclick` event to the `image` and use [Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) to get the `a` parent element as you have in your code:

```js
document.getElementById('myImage').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.log(e.target.parentElement.href);
};
```

```html
<a href="someline">
  <img id="myImage" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

We really need to see more code, but **if** the handler is attached to the `a` elements, use `e.currentTarget` (or `this`) rather than `e.target`.

---

If not (e.g., you're using event delegation or something), then just check the `tagName` and use `parentNode` until you find the `a`:

```
var el = e.target;
while (el && el.tagName !== "A") {
    el = el.parentNode;
}
if (el) {
    console.log(el.href);
}
```