# How to use addEventListener with all HTML buttons, checkbox, radio, select and href

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I would like to add listener only to HTML buttons, checkbox, radio, select and anchor tag(href) on element level, irrespective of element ID or name.

Means, i would like to listen the click event whenever any button, checkbox, radio, select or anchor tag(href) clicked on a webpage. how can i achieve this using javascript. Can somebody help!

Comment: `href` isn't a HTML element

Comment: Loop through `getElementsByTagName()` or attach event to the `document` then check the element type.

Comment: @Script47: Can you give me some sample code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript attach an onclick event to all links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492344/javascript-attach-an-onclick-event-to-all-links)

Comment: @Script47: But it shows only for a tag but i want the same for select, radio, checkbox and button also.

Comment: @GreenComputers please read the second answer.

Comment: @GreenComputers You can just use `document.querySelectorAll()` to select all the clickable elements in the page, please check [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936242/3669624) for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$("button, [type='checkbox'], [type='radio'], select, [href]").each(function () {
    $(this).on("click", function () {
        // STUFF
    });
});
```

If you want to use plain JS:

```
var things = document.querySelectorAll("button, [type='checkbox'], [type='radio'], select, [href]");

for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
   things[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
       // STUFF
   });
}
```

Comment: Instead creating the same event function multiple times (for every element), I would prefer to create it only once and then assign it in the second param of `addEventListener()`. Except... JS is intelligent enough to recognize identical functions and omit creating them in the memory multiple times - I don't know that.

Comment: @masterpreenz: It works well for all elements except for [href]. can u confirm me the reason pls..

Comment: `href` is not an element, but an attribute of the element `a` (anchor tag). Replace the `[href]` with `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use **[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to select all the clickable elements in the page:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input, button, a, select").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input, button, a, select").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<button>Click this button</button>

<input type="button" value="Click it" />


<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Accept<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Refuse<br>

<label><input type="checkbox"/>Send me notifications</label><br/>
<a href="#">Click the link</a>
```

**document.querySelectorAll()**

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.
>
> where
>
> - elementList is a non-live NodeList of element objects.
> - selectors is a    string containing one or more CSS selectors
>     separated by commas.

Comment: Can u add a demo with <a> element.

Answer (score 0):

Native javascript example :

```js
var all_button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
var all_radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
var all_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")

 
function click () {
 console.log("native")   
}

function ADD_CLICK_EVENT_TO_HTML_TAGS_ARRAY ( _array_ ) {

 for (var i=0; i<_array_.length; i++) {
 
  if (_array_[i].tagName == "input"){
     if (_array_[i].type == "radio" ) { 
        _array_[i].addEventListener("click" , click , false)
     }
  }
  else{
    _array_[i].addEventListener("click" , click , false)
  }
 
 }

}

ADD_CLICK_EVENT_TO_HTML_TAGS_ARRAY ( all_button ) 
ADD_CLICK_EVENT_TO_HTML_TAGS_ARRAY ( all_radio ) 
ADD_CLICK_EVENT_TO_HTML_TAGS_ARRAY ( all_select )
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Click Me1!</button>
<button type="button">Click Me2!</button>
<button type="button">Click Me3!</button>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
```