# Undefined href for some clickable elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get link (url of clickable elements) with the left mouse click, next method doesn't work for all elements:

```
function callback(e) {
    if (e.button != 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    alert(e.target.href);
}
document.addEventListener('click', callback, true);
```

For example for some elements on Youtube site - titles or thumbnails (all of them are clickable and they lead to some video/playlist):

[image]

[image]

href is `undefined`

but it's clickable and Google Chrome browser shows a preview of link to which this element leads:

[image]

**UPDATE**

The problem that some A tags on Youtube site wraps other elements inside them: `<a href="..."><span>...<span/><div.......></a>`

I tried debug mode (inspect), selected some of such element to inspect and it picked `<span>` inside of `<a>`.

**Additional Solution**: https://jsfiddle.net/z2huqjjh/2/ (will be good solution if links (A tags) are dynamically being added to a page)

Comment: It could be that the thing you click doesn't actually have an href attribute and opens a link in some other way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, events bubble. This means that you could have an element that is nested within 100 others. Clicking on that nested element will cause a `click` event and that event will propagate up through all the ancestor elements until it is either cancelled or reaches the `window`.

Now, just about everything in the `document` is clickable. Just because something is clickable doesn't mean it will navigate to a URL, like an `<a>` element does.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Thanks for clicking me!");
});
```

```html
<div>I'm a &lt;div&gt; and I don't have an 'href'. But, click me anyway</div>
```

Since only a few elements actually have an `href` attribute, you could alter your code to look only at those:

```js
function callback(e) {
  if (e.button != 0 ) {
    return;
  } 
  alert(e.currentTarget.href);
}

// Get all the anchors and place into an array
var anchorArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));

// Loop through the anchors
anchorArray.forEach(function(anchor){
  // Assign a click event handler to each. When the click event
  // bubbles to the element, the callback will be called
  anchor.addEventListener('click', callback);
});
```

```html
<div>I'm a div - click me anyway</div>
<a href="#"><span>I'm a span inside of an anchor, click me too!</span></a>
```

Comment: yes I understand that I have to check for a tag (I have it in my code, just didn't include in my question here), seems the problem that some A tags on Youtube site wraps other elements inside them: `<a href="..."><other element></><other.....></a>`

Comment: updated my answer, it chooses `Span `on click event (an example with Youtube element), not `A`, it seems I have to get `Span` parent (`A`) with javascript code

Comment: @user924 Updated answer to show solution for your scenario. You only need to set up your click handler on the anchors, not the entire document. Then, you don't have to worry about `e.target` having or not having an `href`.

Comment: yeah I just chose this method (which will work only for A tags without nested elements) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492344/javascript-attach-an-onclick-event-to-all-links#comment79603624_8496919

Comment: @user924 Look at my answer. It will work for nested elements. I'm showing that. Not to mention that you should not use `.getElementsByTagName()` unless you want a "live" node list, which isn't right for most use cases.

Comment: yes I understand it will work, I just thought my first method would be faster (wanted to avoid querySelectorAll and loops)

Comment: @user924 Faster isn't always better. There's nothing at all wrong with `.querySelectorAll()` (it's the workhorse of the DOM API) and loops are the effective way to do a lot with a little code.

Comment: @user924 You are not using the code that I wrote. See **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/rp3j6sf8/1/)**. You are using `e.target`, I am using `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: oh.. my fault.. I just didn't look at your `callback` function changes, but I earlier copied it, everything was working then somehow I guess I changed to my old and it stopped working, so I just confused myself. But now everything is definitely ok, Thanks!)

Comment: omg I also forgot about one function that I used in one of my project, `getLink(e)` (I remember I found it somewhere): https://jsfiddle.net/z2huqjjh/1/

Comment: @user924 Yeah, but my solution is much more performant as it doesn't try or even need to start looking at parent elements. That essentially defeats the purpose and behavior of event bubbling. Let bubbling do the work here.

Comment: and it's also worse because it would try to find a link (call `getLink(e)` function) every time we click somewhere even if it's not A element is clicked, so yeah it's better to get only A elements `(querySelectorAll("a")`) and set listener to them

Comment: I found out that only `getLink(e)` works better for me, `(querySelectorAll("a"))` won't get all links when page is loading (for example on Youtube site) and also `getLink(e)` will be good solution if links (A tags) are dynamically being added to a page

Comment: Just change my solution by replacing .querySelectorAll() with .getElementsByClassNsme() and remove the dot in front of the class name in the passed string. .getLink() is not a good solution.

Comment: Verified that `e.currentTarget.href` is the right one to get the url, even when debugging `e.currentTarget` shows `null` by `console.log`.