# Get nearest <p> tag text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here are the p tags that auto populate on page load with multiple options.

```
<div  id="bunchOfChoices" class="choices">
            {% for user in users %}
            <p id="searchOpts" class="searchOpts">{{user.username}}</p>
            {% endfor %}</div>


<script>
var opts = document.getElementById('searchOpts');
opts.onclick = function(event) {
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

the_user = target.innerHTML;
href= "/../users/"+String(the_user);
window.location=href;

};
</script>
```

This code seems to only get the first "searchOpt". Also, I am aware I can use `<a>` tags instead of this method.

Comment: if you need to find all p tags with id then use Document.querySelectorAll(). read it here how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Use Document.querySelectorAll() for all case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Answer (score 3):

ID should be unique for one element. If you need to categorize multiple p with same name, you can use class and then use below one:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("searchOpts");
```

Demo:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('searchOpts')[1]);
```

```html
<p id="searchOpts1" class="searchOpts">Name 1</p>
<p id="searchOpts2" class="searchOpts">Name 2</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things here:

**Misuse of `id`**

You [should never](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) have multiple elements on the page with the same `id`. You should use `class` and leave the `id` out.

**Assigning `onclick` handlers:**

You can use the classes to assign `onclick` handlers as follows:

```
<script>
    for (let opt of Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("searchOpts"))) {
        opt.onclick = () => {
            window.location.href = "/../users/" + opt.textContent;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML pages should only ever have one element marked with any particular `id`. Here you are marking all `<p>` elements with the id `searchOpts`. This is incorrect.

You would be better to remove the `id` and just use the `class`.  Then search for all elements with that class:

```
var allSearchOpts = document.querySelectorAll(".searchOpts");
```

This returns an element list, so you need to loop over the list to set the click handler on each element.

```
allSearchOpts.forEach( function(el) {
     el.onclick = ...
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.getElementById` this gets the first item with this id. when you use IDs the ID name must be unique.

If you need to add the event for multi-elements use `queryselectorall` and add your event for every item.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492344/javascript-attach-an-onclick-event-to-all-links#answer-48810970)

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery, you can get the next `p` by using

```
$(this).next("p");
```

in your onclick function.