# How to run a function from a link created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function in a javascript file that adds a link to a paragraph that I created in the HTML file. I want to call a function that is defined in the javascript file when the user clicks the link.

My HTML:

`<p id="para"></p>`

My JavaScript:

```
var paraHTML = document.getElementById("para");

function addLink(id) {
    paraHTML.innerHTML += '<a id="' + id + '" onclick="clickedTest(); return false;">Click me!</a>'
}

function clickedTest() {
    console.log('here');
}
```

I have also tried using href e.g.

`paraHTML.innerHTML += '<a id="' + id + '" href="javascricpt:clickedTest();">Click me!</a>'`

But both ways give me an error saying: `ReferenceError: clickedTest is not defined`

I have tried using the following code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492344/javascript-attach-an-onclick-event-to-all-links) question but the number of links is constantly changing whilst my code is running which makes it difficult to use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log('here')
    }
}
```

The `addLink()` function is called elsewhere in my javascript program several times

Comment: You can use onClick() directly inside para, 
<p onclick="addLink()"></p>

Comment: What is the scope of the `clickedTest()` function? Do you have it inside a load handler? Since your code is working as expected. Make sure the function is in the global scope.

Comment: its working fine for me bro

Comment: You can also try document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", clickedTest); after adding the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using innerHTML to create content is usually slow and is usually discouraged, a more organic approach will be to create the element pragmatically and then adding event listener to that element. For example,

```
var elem = document.createElement('a');
elem.addEventListener('click', myClickHandler);
elem.innerText = 'My Tag';
paraHTML.appendChild(elem)

function myClickHandler(e) {
  console.log('a is clicked')
}
```

This will not only fix your problem but will make your code more manageable

Comment: Thank you, I had noticed my program had been running very slowly

Comment: Good answer but `documeent` should be `document` ;)

Comment: Good work. Also better to keep using `;` on all lines or none of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function callMe(){
}
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.href="javascript:callMe();";
newLink.innerHTML="this is a link";

paraHTML.appendChild(newLink);
```